# Toggle Opacity on other DIVs

Tags: jquery

I was looking for a simple way, probably with jQuery, of lowering the opacity of all other DIVs when hovered and returning them back in on out.

```
<div id="fade_container">
     <div id="fade1">Content</div>
     <div id="fade2">Content</div>
     <div id="fade3">Content</div>
     <div id="fade4">Content</div>
</div>
```

**For example:** When **fade2** is hovered **fade1**, **fade3** and **fade4** should lose some opacity.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

```
$('#fade_container div').hover(function(){  // mouseover 
  $(this).siblings().fadeTo('fast',0.5);  
}, function(){  // mouseout 
  $(this).siblings().fadeTo('fast',1.0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6XygU/4/

Comment: Perfect, I added a quick stop() before the fadeTo for a smoother effect, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.faded {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('#fade_container div').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings().addClass('faded');
},function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('faded');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking at [jquery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) library..
this library does exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$('div', '#fade_container').hover(function(){
   $('div', '#fade_container').not(this).stop().animate({
     opacity: .2
   }, 500);

   $(this).stop().animate({
     opacity: 1
   }, 500);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sj8x5/1/